# gorp: near "auto_increment": syntax error

Tags: sql, go, gorp

I am trying to write simple program to insert the row in the table using the `gorp` but I am getting error on creating the table.

Following is the code:

```
package main

import _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
import "database/sql"
import "fmt"
import "github.com/go-gorp/gorp"

func main() {

        type Person struct {
                Identi  int64
                Created int64
                FName   string
                LName   string
        }

        db, _ := sql.Open("sqlite3", "mydb.db")

        dbmap := &gorp.DbMap{Db: db, Dialect: gorp.MySQLDialect{"InnoDB", "UTF8"}}

        _ = dbmap.AddTable(Person{}).SetKeys(true, "Identi")

        err := dbmap.CreateTables()
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("table not created : " + err.Error())
        }

        person := &Person{
                FName: "Joe",
                LName: "Smith",
        }
        err = dbmap.Insert(person)

        if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("err" + err.Error())
        }
}
```

I am getting following error:

```
table not created : near "auto_increment": syntax error
err no such table: Person
```

I would appreciate your help!

Comment: Why are you using MySQL dialect with an SQLite database?

Comment: @Ainar-G could you please explain me about the dialect, I took the code sample from the http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2013/11/04/want-to-work-with-databases-in-golang-lets-try-some-gorp/. I am using sqlite3.

Comment: There are different kinds of databases. That example used MySQL, while you are using SQLite. Each database needs its own dialect. See my answer.

Comment: BTW, you almost never want/need to directly call `Error()`; just do `fmt.Println("table not created:", err)`. (And please tell me that you don't actually ignore error returns with `_` in the real code but just did that here to stream line the question).

Comment: thanks @DaveC for the suggestion +1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using MySQL dialect with an SQLite database. Change

```
dbmap := &gorp.DbMap{Db: db, Dialect: gorp.MySQLDialect{"InnoDB", "UTF8"}}
```

to

```
dbmap := &gorp.DbMap{Db: db, Dialect: gorp.SqliteDialect{}}
```